# Illegal string offset

Tags: php, foreach, fetch

```
$sql = "SELECT images.id, title, image, note 
        FROM news 
        INNER JOIN images ON news.id = images.id_news
        WHERE news.id=?
        ORDER BY images.id DESC";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));

$e = $stmt->fetch();

foreach($e[] as $row)
{
    $e[]=array(
        'title'=>$row['title'],
        'image'=>$row['image'],
        'note'=>$row['note']
        );
}
```

And then I have

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Wazup.mn\inc\functions.inc.php on line 20

Warning: Illegal string offset 'image' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Wazup.mn\inc\functions.inc.php on line 21

Warning: Illegal string offset 'note' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Wazup.mn\inc\functions.inc.php on line 22
```

Answer (score 0):

leave out the `[]`in the `foreach`statement

```
foreach($e as $key => $val)
{
    $key=$val
}
```

But, even simpler, you can do

```
extract($e);
```

Comment: I'm using PDO so this code $stmt->setfetchmode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); i tried this now its working perfect

Answer (score 0):

you can use FETCH_COLUMN in the fetchAll function and then use the foreach loop

```
$e = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
foreach($e as $row)
{
    $e=array(
        'title'=>$row['title'],
        'image'=>$row['image'],
        'note'=>$row['note']
        );
}
```

Comment: tnx for your answer $stmt->setfetchmode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); i tried this now its working perfect